# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection with passport

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js

I have the following userSchema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: String,
password: String,
userName: String,
fname: String,
lname: String,
userType: Number,
subscribedThreads: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Threads"
    }
]
});
// add passport methods
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
// export modules to be used by the file requiring it
module.exports = mongoose.model("Users",userSchema);
```

The first entry into the collection occurs as it should but the next ones give

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: KManV3.users 
index: username_1 dup key: { : null }]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: KManV3.users index: 
username_1 dup key: { : null }',
driver: true,
code: 11000,
index: 0,
errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: KManV3.users index: 
username_1 dup key: { : null }',
getOperation: [Function],
toJSON: [Function],
toString: [Function] 
}
```

Also, **dbname.users.getIndexes()** gives:

```
> db.users.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "KManV3.users"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "password" : 1
    },
    "name" : "password_1",
    "ns" : "KManV3.users",
    "background" : true
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "username" : 1
    },
    "name" : "username_1",
    "ns" : "KManV3.users",
    "background" : true
}
]
```

Apparently every property of schema has been set as unique and I can't add data into collections even if the data is totally different. I'm not sure if it's due to integration of passport.

Comment: Checked the question first, the error shows even if I add all details and leave nothing empty. So, I'm pretty sure it's not caused due to duplicate values like in the "possible duplicate thread"

Comment: Did you not want the unique constraint? A document is considered not-unique if it shares ANY property value with another document, including null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [options](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#options) for `passport-local-mongoose`:

> usernameField: specifies the field name that holds the username. Defaults to 'username'.
>
> usernameUnique : specifies if the username field should be enforced to be unique by a mongodb index or not. Defaults to true.

Which explains why your collection has a unique index on the (non-existent-in-your-schema) `username` field.

If you don't actually set this field in documents that you add to the database, MongoDB will use `null`, and once the first document has been inserted, a subsequent document (also with the field value `null` for `username`) will throw an E11000 error.

So first, remove the index on `username` (and also `password`, I assume you once marked that field as `unique` in your schema), and set the proper field name for `passport-local-mongoose` to use:

```
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField : 'userName' });
```

(or `email`, if you want that field to be used as unique user identifier)

Comment: So, username in the schema gets unique property from passport?

Comment: @about99ninjas from `passport-local-mongoose`, yes. You can change the name of the field that should get that unique property, as explained.

Comment: That made sense, fixed it by removing the passport-local-mongoose. Will find a workaround.

Comment: @about99ninjas you can always tell it not to create that unique index, that's what the `usernameUnique` option does.

Comment: I need unique on username to avoid any errors but I also need them to stay null until user registers. Thus, it's kind of a contradiction. Ended up creating another collection for username and password and created a new property in user 'auth = null' which is set to objectID of auth of specific user on registration.

Comment: @about99ninjas you can also create a unique [_sparse_](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) index manually (instead of having `passport-local-mongoose` create the index for you). A sparse index will allow `null` values without causing E11000